# how to install android app remotely by sending image?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to install any android app directly via sending any image or directly on clicking on web link?

when anyone click on link or download image application directly starts downloading and install without manual interaction of user without rooting of android phone.

Comment: No, the closest you can get is a link to the Play Store (which lets the user install the app from the Play Store application) or a direct download link to the apk (if the user opens it after it is downloaded, the installer will open - but only if it is allowed in the settings). If this were not the case, you could get a virus on your phone simply by browsing the internet.

Comment: This is actually a **malware** behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Auto execution/installation of a downloaded file are disabled in every main stream Operating systems, be it windows, android, etc.